# How to convert an HTML table into a Python dictionary

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML excerpt in a format of a Python list that I'd like to turn into a dictionary. It is a timetable for everyday of the week.

```
[u'
<table class="hours table">\n
    <tbody>\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Mon</th>\n
            <td>\n <span class="nowrap">2:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">3:00 pm</span>
                <br><span class="nowrap">5:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">10:00 pm</span>\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Tue</th>\n
            <td>\n <span class="nowrap">2:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">3:00 pm</span>
                <br><span class="nowrap">5:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">10:00 pm</span>\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Wed</th>\n
            <td>\n <span class="nowrap">2:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">3:00 pm</span>
                <br><span class="nowrap">5:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">10:00 pm</span>\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n <span class="nowrap open">Open now</span>\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Thu</th>\n
            <td>\n <span class="nowrap">2:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">3:00 pm</span>
                <br><span class="nowrap">5:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">10:00 pm</span>\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Fri</th>\n
            <td>\n <span class="nowrap">2:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">3:00 pm</span>
                <br><span class="nowrap">5:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">10:00 pm</span>\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Sat</th>\n
            <td>\n <span class="nowrap">5:00 pm</span> - <span class="nowrap">10:00 pm</span>\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n
        <tr>\n
            <th scope="row">Sun</th>\n
            <td>\n Closed\n </td>\n
            <td class="extra">\n </td>\n </tr>\n\n </tbody>\n </table>']
```

The wishful output is:

```
{
'Mon': ['2:00pm - 3:00pm', '5:00pm - 10:00pm'], 
'Tue': ['2:00pm - 3:00pm', '5:00pm - 10:00pm'], 
'Wed': ['2:00pm - 3:00pm', '5:00pm - 10:00pm'], 
'Thu': ['2:00pm - 3:00pm', '5:00pm - 10:00pm'], 
'Fri': ['2:00pm - 3:00pm', '5:00pm - 10:00pm'], 
'Sat': '5:00pm - 10:00pm', 
'Sun': 'Closed'
}
```

How would you achieve this in Python 3.x? I would not mind if the 'Sat' and 'Sun' keys have values in a list format if that'd help at all. Thank you for your thoughts in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

d = OrderedDict()
for th, td in zip(soup.select('th'), soup.select('td')[::2]):
    d[th.text.strip()] = td.text.strip().splitlines()

pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([('Mon', ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']),
             ('Tue', ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']),
             ('Wed', ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']),
             ('Thu', ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']),
             ('Fri', ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']),
             ('Sat', ['5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']),
             ('Sun', ['Closed'])])
```

Answer (score 22):

Here's a solution which first reads into Pandas DataFrame, and then converts to dictionary as in your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html(html_string)
df = dfs[0]  # pd.read_html reads in all tables and returns a list of DataFrames
```

Giving:

```
     0                                      1         2
0  Mon  2:00 pm - 3:00 pm  5:00 pm - 10:00 pm       NaN
1  Tue  2:00 pm - 3:00 pm  5:00 pm - 10:00 pm       NaN
2  Wed  2:00 pm - 3:00 pm  5:00 pm - 10:00 pm  Open now
3  Thu  2:00 pm - 3:00 pm  5:00 pm - 10:00 pm       NaN
4  Fri  2:00 pm - 3:00 pm  5:00 pm - 10:00 pm       NaN
5  Sat                     5:00 pm - 10:00 pm       NaN
6  Sun                                 Closed       NaN
```

Then use `groupby` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
summary = {k: v.iloc[0, 1].split('  ') for k, v in df.groupby(0)}
```

Giving:

```
{'Fri': ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm'],
 'Mon': ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm'],
 'Sat': ['5:00 pm - 10:00 pm'],
 'Sun': ['Closed'],
 'Thu': ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm'],
 'Tue': ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm'],
 'Wed': ['2:00 pm - 3:00 pm', '5:00 pm - 10:00 pm']}
```

You may need to edit slightly if splitting on exactly two spaces won't always work for your opening times data format.

Answer (score 5):

Use a library to parse the HTML, something like this:

```
import pandas as panda
url = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states'
tables = panda.read_html(url)
sp500_table = tables[0] #Selecting the first table (for example)
```