# Which AWS infrastructure to choose to write an automated application in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, architecture, infrastructure

I have a basic background in DS with Python and I try now the first time to build an application and I need a bit advise which infrastructure to choose on AWS and how to structure the application. The code I can develop/google on my own :)

The main question is: Where/On which platform of AWS should happen Step 2. I guess I miss there some basic knowledge of applications and therefore I have problems to google the problem myself.

What should happen by the application:

1. On a website a user types in values in a form and this values are sended  somewhere so be processed. (Already coded)
2. Now, this values (so far an email with the values) has to be sent somewhere to be processed. Here I do not know in which infrastructure of AWS I can write an application that can receive this values (/email) directly and process it automatically?
   3./4. Automated process of values, pdf creation and sending etc.

Goal is that always when a user uses the website and sends the email, that the automated process is triggered.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You want to send the email somewhere in AWS and process it or you want to send the data/values from the form and process that?

Comment: I'm sorry for the fluffy description!

Finally it just matters that the values typed in on the website are processed automatically somewhere. 
(The email is just what I got programmed so far to transport the values ^^)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have access to the mailbox to which user form data will be sent via email, You can then read the email data using **imap** module of python and extract the required information either by using **regex** or by some html to dict conversion module, please find below link for html to dict conversion.

[How to convert an HTML table into a Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657000/how-to-convert-an-html-table-into-a-python-dictionary).

Having said all that I would strongly recommend you to use **AWS EC2** instance to host your application, **NGNIX** as web server, **postgress** as database and most importantly **Django** as the webframe work, you should have the user fill the require data in form and send that form directly to the back end server which can then save it directly to your database (there is no need to send the data via email), if you have any queries please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a "fanning out" architecture with something like Eventbridge or SNS topic.

When your user submits form, you publish a message to an SNS topic.

That topic can send an email, and also send the data to a  backend service like lambda to save to something like DynamoDB or something like RDS MySQL.